# How to ping WSL from another machine

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ping, wsl2

I am using a PC with Windows 10 Home with WSL2 Ubuntu installed, and I would like to ping my WSL instance from my laptop. Because WSL uses a NAT virtual adapter, it's not on the same network as the laptop.

I tried creating a proxy using:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8090 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8090 connectaddress=172.23.116.251
```

and allowing the port using:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”Open Port 8090 for WSL2” dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8090
```

yet I was unable to ping WSL from my laptop.

How can I ping WSL from another device in the network?
Is there a way to change it from NAT to Bridged?

Note: I am able to ping the host (my PC) from my laptop.

Edit: I tried

`ping 172.23.116.251`

`Test-NetConnection 172.23.116.251`

`Test-NetConnection 172.23.116.251 -p 8090`

`Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.56 -p 8090`

In the last one I tried to ping the host PC on port 8090 (I wasn't sure if I should ping WSL directly or ping the host pc and let it redirect the ping to WSL)

Host-IP:  192.168.0.56

WSL-IP:  172.23.116.251

Comment: Could you add your ping command to your post? Note that the standard ping command does not use TCP or UDP. It uses ICMP that has no ports. Using [telnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/telnet) might be a better test in some cases.

Comment: Why is your Windows machine and your WSL instance on two entirely different subnets? Even though WSL uses a virtual NAT adapter it can still be configured to the same subnet. What will work is configuring OpenSSH on the WIndows machine then connecting to WSL through OpenSSH.

Comment: @Ramhound: ...isn't that literally because it's on a different network adapter? You don't configure two networks to use the same subnet number.

Comment: @user1686 - I didn't suggested the exact same IP Address I suggeste the same subnet.  When you are running a virtual machine running on a host, you can configure the virtual machine, to be connected to the same subnet as the host machine. You certainly can connected it to a different subnet but you would have to provide a route to that subnet.

Comment: @Ramhound: Same subnet still doesn't make sense when they're two separate interfaces (and the host is routing between them). If WSL was configured to be bridged to the host's physical network, then sure, it would just be in the same subnet as the host... but that's not the default, the default is to have WSL on a separate virtual network, so I don't see any reason to be surprised that OP would have it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **WSL2**, you basically need to do port-forwarding on the host to WSL, (which you've already done). From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan):

> Here's an example PowerShell command to add a port proxy that listens on port 4000 on the host and connects it to port 4000 to the WSL 2 VM with IP address 192.168.101.100.
>
> ```
> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=4000 connectaddress=192.168.101.100
> ```

---

That said, portproxy will not work for default ping (ICMP). You can use `Test-NetConnection`, but WSL **must** be listening on the port that you're forwarding to (8090 in your question). For example, try forwarding port 2222 on the host to port 22 on WSL, then do `Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.56 -p 2222`